# How can to remove all blank space between tags in Smarty?

Tags: smarty

Imagine we have this code in editor:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div>Hello 1</div>
  <div>Hello 2</div>
  <div>Hello 3</div>
</div>
```

How to remove all spaces between html tags? So the result should be:

```
<div class="menu"><div>Hello 1</div><div>Hello 2</div><div>Hello 3</div</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i solved it via custom block function, I created new PHP file **"smarty/plugins/block.minify.php"** with this code:

```
function smarty_block_minify($params, $content, &$smarty, &$repeat) {
    if (!$repeat) {
        if (isSet($content)) {
            // HTML Minifier
            $input = $content;
            if(trim($input) === "") return $input;
            // Remove extra white-space(s) between HTML attribute(s)
            $input = preg_replace_callback('#<([^\/\s<>!]+)(?:\s+([^<>]*?)\s*|\s*)(\/?)>#s', function($matches) {
                return '<' . $matches[1] . preg_replace('#([^\s=]+)(\=([\'"]?)(.*?)\3)?(\s+|$)#s', ' $1$2', $matches[2]) . $matches[3] . '>';
            }, str_replace("\r", "", $input));
            // Minify inline CSS declaration(s)
            if(strpos($input, ' style=') !== false) {
                $input = preg_replace_callback('#<([^<]+?)\s+style=([\'"])(.*?)\2(?=[\/\s>])#s', function($matches) {
                    return '<' . $matches[1] . ' style=' . $matches[2] . minify_css($matches[3]) . $matches[2];
                }, $input);
            }
            return preg_replace(
                array(
                    // t = text
                    // o = tag open
                    // c = tag close
                    // Keep important white-space(s) after self-closing HTML tag(s)
                    '#<(img|input)(>| .*?>)#s',
                    // Remove a line break and two or more white-space(s) between tag(s)
                    '#(<!--.*?-->)|(>)(?:\n*|\s{2,})(<)|^\s*|\s*$#s',
                    '#(<!--.*?-->)|(?<!\>)\s+(<\/.*?>)|(<[^\/]*?>)\s+(?!\<)#s', // t+c || o+t
                    '#(<!--.*?-->)|(<[^\/]*?>)\s+(<[^\/]*?>)|(<\/.*?>)\s+(<\/.*?>)#s', // o+o || c+c
                    '#(<!--.*?-->)|(<\/.*?>)\s+(\s)(?!\<)|(?<!\>)\s+(\s)(<[^\/]*?\/?>)|(<[^\/]*?\/?>)\s+(\s)(?!\<)#s', // c+t || t+o || o+t -- separated by long white-space(s)
                    '#(<!--.*?-->)|(<[^\/]*?>)\s+(<\/.*?>)#s', // empty tag
                    '#<(img|input)(>| .*?>)<\/\1\x1A>#s', // reset previous fix
                    '#(&nbsp;)&nbsp;(?![<\s])#', // clean up ...
                    // Force line-break with `&#10;` or `&#xa;`
                    '#&\#(?:10|xa);#',
                    // Force white-space with `&#32;` or `&#x20;`
                    '#&\#(?:32|x20);#',
                    // Remove HTML comment(s) except IE comment(s)
                    '#\s*<!--(?!\[if\s).*?-->\s*|(?<!\>)\n+(?=\<[^!])#s'
                ),
                array(
                    "<$1$2</$1\x1A>",
                    '$1$2$3',
                    '$1$2$3',
                    '$1$2$3$4$5',
                    '$1$2$3$4$5$6$7',
                    '$1$2$3',
                    '<$1$2',
                    '$1 ',
                    "\n",
                    ' ',
                    ""
                ),
                $input);

            return $input;
        }
    }
}
```

And now I am able to call it via `{minify}some html code{/minify}`.

Comment: Where does the minify_css function come from?

Comment: See here :)

https://gist.github.com/Rodrigo54/93169db48194d470188f

Answer (score 1):

Use [{strip}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.strip.tpl)

```
{strip}
<div class="menu">
  <div>Hello 1</div>
  <div>Hello 2</div>
  <div>Hello 3</div>
</div>
{/strip}
```

If you want to remove spaces even in the same line, its a bit more complicated, you'll have to use capture and do a regular expression replacement (or create your own plugin for that):

```
{capture name="code"}
{strip}
<div id="1"></div> <div id="2"></div>
{/strip}
{/capture}
{$smarty.capture.code|regex_replace:'/\>[\s\r\t\n]*\</':'><'}
```

However that can produce unexpected results when a space between tags is supposed to be there. Consider i.e.:

```
<strong>one hundred</strong> <span class="unit">grams</span>
```

removing the spaces will render the html as

**one hundred**grams

Comment: If you use `{strip}` function on block of HTML, there will always stay one blank character between HTML tags. For example if you have `<div id="1"></div>   <div id="2"></div>` it will generate `<div id="1"></div> <div id="2"></div>` so there will be one space. I want to eliminate all the blank characters between tags (spaces, tabs, new lines etc).

Comment: Your initial example didn't mention spaces between tags in the same line. I've updated the answer. Take notice of the possible drawbacks, though.

Comment: this worked so damn well, even when i had asked the admin he didn't point me to this simple tag lol and told me to put comments everywhere like {* *} on all the empty spaces...

Answer (score 1):

If you can't access Smarty's installation directory to install the plugin above, you can do the following:

```
<!-- "strip" removes line breaks -->
{capture name="nospacesbetweentags"}
{strip}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        </div>
    </div>
{/strip}
{/capture}
<!-- this removes spaces & tabs between tags -->
{$smarty.capture.nospacesbetweentags|replace:"> <":"><"|replace:">  <":"><"}
```

I don't know if regex replacement is better, but this works fine for me.

**EDIT:** `{strip}` doesn't work on included subtemplates (`{strip}{include "..."}{/strip}`). Therefore, `|strip` modifier is necessary:

```
{capture name="nospacesbetweentags"}
    <div id="row1" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        </div>
    </div>
    {include "row2.tpl"}
{/capture}
<!-- |strip already modifies multiple tabs into a sigle space -->
{$smarty.capture.nospacesbetweentags|strip|replace:"> <":"><"}
```